# Inscribe N circles(C1) with constant radius and M circles(C2) with X radius into rectangle with width A and height B

Tags: geometry, algebra

I need to cover rectangle with 2 types of circles C1 and C2

N circles C1 with fixed radius R

M circles C2 with X radius(maximum possible radius depending of amount of circles)

Inscribed in rectangle with dimensions A by B

[image]

So basically I need to find X

Comment: Is this an actual coding question?

Comment: Your figure doesn't look like a "cover" of the rectangle. Don't you mean "pack inside without overlap" ?

Comment: Yes, pack inside without overlap. But radius of C1 is constant

Comment: What's your reason to do that ? Maybe you can modify the problem to make it more tractable ?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a terrible problem, intuitively non-polynomial because of the combinatorial aspect.

I would address it with a stochastic method, such as simulated annealing.

If you choose a value for X, the placement step becomes a modified Poisson disk sampling problem (modified in that there are two different radii to be considered).